# Covering N sets of contiguous integers with minimum nos

Tags: algorithm

We are Given N sets of contiguous integers. Each such set is defined by two numbers. Ex : 2,5 represents a set containing 2,3,4,5. We have to print minimum nos. of numbers to select in order to cover all N sets. A nos. is said to cover a set if it is contained in the set.
Ex: Given sets [2,5] , [3,4] , [10,100]. We can choose for example {3,10} so we cover up all 3 sets. Hence answer is 2.

I can't find a proper algorithm for N<=5000.

Comment: did you mean continuous?

Comment: @benji : Yes i meant continous.

Comment: It reads contiguous which is i think also incorrect

Comment: "Contiguous" is the *correct* word.  "Continuous" wouldn't make sense here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `O(nlogn)` approach to solve the problem:

1. Sort the sets by the last element (for example, your example will be sorted as `[3,4], [2,5] , [10,100]`).
2. Choose the end of the first interval
3. Remove all intersecting sets
4. If there is some uncovered set, return to 2.

**Example** (based on your example):

1. sort - your list of sets is sorted as `l =[3,4], [2,5] , [10,100]`
2. Choose 4
3. Remove the covered sets, you now have `l=[10,100]`
4. back to 2 - choose 100
5. Remove the last entry from the list `l=[]`
6. Stop clause is reached, you are done with two points: 4,100.

Correctness Proof (Guidelines) by @j_random_hacker:

> Some element in that first (after sorting) range [i,j] must be
>   included in the answer, or that range would not be covered. Its
>   rightmost element j covers at least the same set of ranges as any
>   other element in [i,j]. Why? Suppose to the contrary that there was
>   some element k < j that covered a range that is not covered by j: then
>   that range must have an endpoint < j, which contradicts the fact that
>   [i,j] has the smallest endpoint (which we know because it's the first
>   in the sorted list)

Comment: Proof sketch of optimality: *Some* element in that first (after sorting) range [i,j] must be included in the answer, or that range would not be covered.  Its rightmost element j covers at least the same set of ranges as any other element in [i,j].  Why?  Suppose to the contrary that there was some element k < j that covered a range that is not covered by j: then that range must have an endpoint < j, which contradicts the fact that [i,j] has the smallest endpoint (which we know because it's the first in the sorted list).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks, knew it went something like that but got stuck, off to bed now. I added your sketch (with credit) to the answer, hope you don't mind (please, remove it if you do, and feel free to edit it as you wish). good night.

Comment: You're welcome!  Of course, I'm glad you added it :)

Answer (score 1):

Note the following is a greedy algorithm that *doesn't work* (see the comments).  I am leaving it here, in case it helps someone else.

I would approach this using a recursive algorithm.  First, note that if the sets are disjoint, then then you need "n" numbers.  Second, the set of "covering" points can be the ends of the sets, so this is a reduced number of options.

You can iterate/recurse your way through this.  The following is a high-level sketch of the algorithm:

One iteration step is:

- Extract the endpoints from all the sets
- Count the number of sets that each endpoint covers
- Choose the endpoint with the maximum coverage

If the maximum coverage is 1, then choose an arbitrary point from each set.

Otherwise, choose the endpoint with the maximum coverage.  If there are ties for the maximum, arbitrarily choose one.  I don't believe it makes a difference when there are ties.

Remove all the sets covered by the endpoint, and add the endpoint to your "coverage points".

Repeat the process until either there are no sets left or the maximum coverage is 1.

Comment: Ties do matter: consider the problem instance {[1,2], [2,3], [3,3], [1,1]}.  Any of {1, 2, 3} covers 2 ranges, but if 2 is picked then 2 more numbers are needed, while if either 1 or 3 is picked, only 1 more number is needed.

Comment: In addition to @j_random_hacker comment,  it s actually more acute, and this algorithm is sub-optimal. consider `[1,2],[3,4],[4,5],[2,5],[5,6],[5,8],[6,7],[8,9]`. The "most covered" end point is 5 (no ties). However, if you happen to chose it, you will need to choose at least 4 more points, totaling in 5 points, while the optimal solution is `{2,4,6,8}`

Comment: @amit beat me by a few seconds to finding a general counterexample!  Here's mine anyway: For the problem instance {[1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [3,4], [3,5], [4,5]}, the optimal solution is {2, 4}.  Both of these numbers cover only 3 ranges each.  Your algorithm would initially choose 3, since it covers 4 ranges, but this will lead to a suboptimal solution, since 2 more numbers are then needed.